# python struct.unpack in Java

Tags: java, python

I am pretty new to Python and have been trying to port a python script in Java.
For a while I have been stuck at the following code logic, trying to convert it to Java but have been unable to do so (probably because I misunderstood what's actually being done)

```
data = unpack('>H', file.read(2))
if data == 0xffff
then //do something
else //do something else
```

now, this is I think is being done in the python script above:-
unpacking a string (I believe, reading first 2 bytes of a file) in hexa-decimal format and then checking if it is value is 0)

Is my perception about unpacking correct ; if not, then what's exactly unpacking doing? Is it getting a substring from the file object via this operation:-

1 - read the file into a byte array

2 - get the first 2 elements of the byte array

then doing what?

Can someone please help me write down the logic as mentioned in python above in Java?

Comment: Take a look at the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module. The above code reads 10 bytes of binary data (as a string) from a file and interprets it as a big-endian unsigned short integer. If that integer is equal to `0xffff` or `65335` in decimal notation, does something and otherwise something else. Can't help you with the java part.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `unpack('>5H', file.read(10))` to unpack 5 big-endian, unsigned short integers into a `tuple`? As is you'll get an exception.

Comment: @eryksun: Sorry I mixed 2 lines of code. You are correct, it was '>5H' for reading 10 bytes and '>H' for 2 bytes. Any idea how this could be done in Java? Java, as far as I know does not have unsigned integers in Java (they are BIG ENDIAN and signed).

Comment: CPython 2.x doesn't have an `unsigned short` type. It has a small integer type based on a C `long` and a big integer type that uses a variable array of C `unsigned short` (if `sys.long_info.bits_per_digit` is 15).

Comment: What CPython `unpack` basically does for format '>H' is to shift in the bytes with bitwise OR (`|`) and left bitshift (`<<`). For example: `unsigned long x = *bytes++; x = (x << 8) | *bytes;`. Then call `PyInt_FromLong(x)` to create a Python `int` object. The '5' modifier just instructs it to do this 5 times.

Comment: This is done generically with function pointer tables and a `Struct` object that parses the format string into an array of `struct _formatdef`, each with a code, size, alignment, and pack/unpack function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you need a BigInteger, because Java native long will not hold anything larger than 64 bits.

It can be initialized using an array of bytes, so you should be fine.